# How would I loop over a data frame and create a dict that stores the column name as a key and the corresponding row index as a value?

Tags: python, pandas

Say if this is my data frame.

```
index | col_1 | col_2| col3
0     |   A   |   B  |  C  
1     |   D   |   E  |  F  
2     |   G   |   H  |  I  
3     |   J   |   K  |  L
```

I want to loop over this dataframe and create 4 dicts structured as the following:

```
{
    "col_1": A,
    "col_2": B,
    "col_3": C
},

{
    "col_1": D,
    "col_2": E,
    "col_3": F
},

{
    "col_1": G,
    "col_2": H,
    "col_3": I
},

{
    "col_1": J,
    "col_2": K,
    "col_3": L
},
```

I ultimately want to prepare this and convert it into a JSON file. I've tried pandas to_json() method, but it does not structure the data in this manner even when I pass in all possible arguments for orient=""

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 2):

In your case using `orient = 'r'`

```
df.to_dict('r')
Out[682]: 
[{'col3': 'C', 'col_1': 'A', 'col_2': 'B'},
 {'col3': 'F', 'col_1': 'D', 'col_2': 'E'},
 {'col3': 'I', 'col_1': 'G', 'col_2': 'H'},
 {'col3': 'L', 'col_1': 'J', 'col_2': 'K'}]
```

Comment: thank you! I'm assuming it was because I was using to_json() instead of to_dict.